# OPCEnum missing from windows7

Tags: windows-7, opc

I need to develop a small OPC client program.
The problem is that for some reason I don't have the OPC Enum service on my computer (windows7)...

How can I get it and from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the OPC Foundation: https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/developer-kits-classic/core-components

"Some reason" would be because it's not something that comes installed with Windows...